# Logging message not storing in the log file using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

My custom log messages are not storing in the log file but displaying in the console. I am not sure my logging configuration is correct.

This is my configuration,

```
application.properties
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.techno.digital=DEBUG
logging.file=digital.log
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Logging class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = 
   LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);    

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        logger.debug("Debug Log ");
        logger.info("Info log");
        logger.error("Error log");
        }       
}
```

Here my logger messages("Debug Log, Info log") are not writing in the log file. But other system logs are writing.

And how do I write logs in the new log file based on the time interval? Now every time my logs are storing in the same file mylogfile.log so file size gets increase rather than, every one hour once new log file should be created with some unique file name and another one hour all logs should be written in the recently created file.

Comment: did you try setting `logging.level` For writing a new log file based on tie interval you need to configure a RollingFileAppender.

Comment: I tried with logging level still I don't get the custom message in the log file. Please look at my latest configuration.

Comment: Is MyApplicatin class inside com.techno.digital package? Did you add logback-spring.xml to the project classpath? Trying to find out if you are overriding Spring Boot's base.xml configuration

Comment: Ootero Thanks for you reply . After adding logback.xml I could see logs in my file.